# RestAssured_Class Not Found_com/github/fge/jsonschema/main/JsonSchemaFactory

Tags: java, rest-assured

Please help me with validating schema of the response body. I am facing a runtime error.:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/github/fge/jsonschema/main/JsonSchemaFactory

```
import io.restassured.RestAssured;
import io.restassured.http.ContentType;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import io.restassured.response.ValidatableResponse;
import static io.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidator.matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath;
import static io.restassured.RestAssured.*;
public class Sample_JsonSchemaValidation {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            //ClassLoader loader = Sample_JsonSchemaValidation.class.getClassLoader();
            //System.out.println(loader.getResource("Sample_JsonSchemaValidation.class"));



    RestAssured.baseURI = "https://reqres.in/";             
                     given().contentType(ContentType.JSON).queryParam("id", 2).
                     when().get("api/users/").                   then().body(matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath("JsonSchemavalidator.json"));              

        }
}
```

Please help resolve the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the below in your POM ?

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The compile dependencies include 2 artifacts, If you do not have them then include those as well in your POM

[image]

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.java-json-tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Sadly, It is not working @Wilfred. I am using java and test NG so physically adding all required JAR's.

Comment: That's the problem then, try to mavenise your project and add the dependencies, you will not have trouble then. If you insist in using a java project then download the json-schema-validator jar from maven and add them to your class path

Comment: - With the earlier setup of Java+TestNG , I kept adding jars and the errors kept popping up. Now I have updated to maven setup and added required maven dependencies and it worked. Thank you

Comment: But why is it so? How does the MAVEN/POM fix the issue?

Comment: Maven is a build automation tool, for any library there may or may not be a dependent library and these are things which we usually miss when we create as a java project. On the other hand, maven helps to download the dependent libraries and add those to the class path as well. This is a very small explanation about maven and I would ask you to read about it on the web if you need more information :)